# Illuminate all islands with minimum lamps

Tags: algorithm

There are N islands, enumerated from 1 to N. Each of them is so small that we can consider them as points on a plane. We are given the Cartesian coordinates of all islands. X-axis is directed towards East and Y-axis is directed towards North.

We need to illuminate all the islands. To do this, we can place lighthouses on some of the islands. We can't place more than one lighthouse on any single island. Each lighthouse can light only one of the 4 quadrants: North-Western, North-Eastern, South-Western or South-Eastern. If some island is located on the border of an illuminated quadrant, it is considered to be illuminated as well. Note that this means that a lighthouse always illuminates it's own island as well.

Now we need to find the smallest possible number of lighthouses required to illuminate all the islands and also we need to tell their configurations — positions and quadrants illuminated as well.

Example : Let we have 5 islands and there location on cartesian plane are:

```
0,0
1,0
2,0
0,-1
0,-2
```

Here, answer is 1 as we can place it on third island facing South West. Also we can place it on 1st or 5th island.

How to approach this problem ? Please help.

It is given that :

```
1 ≤ N ≤ 10^5
Absolute value of each coordinate doesn't exceed 10^9
No two given islands coincide.
```

Comment: This is homework, right? If so, can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: I think it's from one of those problem/puzzle-programming sites but still Wander is right: show us where you got trouble - or give us the url so we can get credits ourselves :D

Comment: to give you some constructive basics: for the few cases you showed you can use brute-force: test every subset of *selected islands* ... of course you will get into trouble with N near 10^5 ;)

Comment: Did I overread it or did he forget to specify the range of those lights?

Comment: @WanderNauta Yeah, I have brute solution, but thats exponential in complexity

Comment: https://www.codechef.com/SEPT15/problems/LIGHTHSE I think the second test case has more than 1 solution and the given output is wrong :)

Comment: @WanderNauta and others, why are people in the algorithm section concerned about demonstrative effort, surmising that Q&A transactions may read better on clean propositions

Comment: @area5one I think this question is a very interesting puzzle, so it could be a great question, but it seems mat7 just copied the entire thing from the link BitTicker posted and tacked a 'please help me do this' at the end. I wouldn't want to upvote that.

Comment: The problem is almost trivial to solve, assuming that those light houses are actually stars (i.e. have unlimited range for practical purposes). Please elaborate whether you really don't want to restrict their range, and if you do want to restrict their range, describe how.

Comment: @WanderNauta I can't help feeling information technology should be exempt from morality, the question would read the same whether motivated by homework or other noble criteria

Comment: If the light has infinite range, the answer is always 1 or 2 (find the two northernmost islands, put a SE lamp on the western one and a SW lamp on the eastern one), so I guess a range is needed to make the question interesting.

Answer (score -1):

man this is too simple..there will be atmost 2 lighthouse is needed to illuminate all island...justbreak this question in two parts..
first part when 1 light house is needed & 2nd part when two light house is needed..
for the first part jus find any one out of four location that is topleft,topright,bottomleft,bootomright if any such cordnate exist one light house should be place there to illumintae all other island

if there exist no such cordinate then 2 cordinate is needed
jus find a cordinate with minimum x and maximum x find if cordinate with maximum x is above than cordinate with minimum x the first light house should be place on cordinate with minimum x & second will be place at cordinate at maximum x (direction of lighthouse of xordinate with min x will be NE & for max x SW) similarly if cordinate with max x is below than than cordinate with min x then first light house should be place on cordinate with min x direction SE & 2nd will be place on cordinate with max x direction NW

## below the full working code in java

https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/8104939

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeSet;
class cordinate{
    int x,y,index;
    cordinate(int x,int y,int index){
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.index=index;
    
  }


}


class add implements Comparable {
    int x, y, Index;

    add(int x, int y, int index) {
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;
       this.Index = index;

   }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return 1;
     }

 }

 class lighthouse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = sc.nextInt();
    while (t-- > 0) {
        TreeSet<add> ts = new<add> TreeSet();
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int minx, maxx, miny, maxy;
        miny = minx = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        maxy = maxx = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {

            int x = sc.nextInt();
            int y = sc.nextInt();

            if (minx > x)
                minx = x;
            if (miny > y)
                miny = y;
            if (maxx < x)
                maxx = x;
            if (maxy < y)
                maxy = y;

            ts.add(new add(x, y, i));
        }

        // System.out.printf("minx =%d maxx=%d miny =%d maxy %d
        ",minx,maxx,miny,maxy);
        boolean f = false;
        for (add add : ts) {
            int x = add.x;
            int y = add.y;
            int index = add.Index;
            if (x == minx && y == miny) {
                System.out.println(1);
                System.out.println(index + " NE");
                f = true;
                break;

            } else if (x == minx && y == maxy) {
                System.out.println(1);
                System.out.println(index + " SE");
                f = true;
                break;

            } else if (x == maxx && y == miny) {
                System.out.println(1);
                System.out.println(index + " NW");
                f = true;
                break;

            } else if (x == maxx && y == maxy) {
                System.out.println(1);
                System.out.println(index + " SW");
                f = true;
                break;

            }

        }
        if (!f) {
            LinkedList al= new LinkedList();
            int minX,y1,maxX,y2 = 0;
            minX=y1=0;
            
            int in1,in2;
            in1=in2=0;
            
            for (add add : ts) {
                int x = add.x;
                int y = add.y;
                int index = add.Index;
                if(x==minx){
                    in1=index;
                    minX=x;
                    y1=y;
                    
                    
                    
                    
                }
                if(x==maxx){
                    in2=index;
                    maxX=x;
                    y2=y;
                    
                
                    
                }
                

            }
            System.out.println(2);
            if(y2>y1){
                
                System.out.println(in1+" NE");
                System.out.println(in2+" SW");
                
            }
            else{
                System.out.println(in1+" SE");
                System.out.println(in2+" NW");
                
                
            }
            
            
            }
        
        }

    }

}
```